# Problemas al guardar datos en una tabla postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, flask

estoy haciendo un proyecto en flask, en la cual recojo datos de una ficha que tengo en una plantilla html, mediante un script de JavaScript recogo esos datos, me lo transforma en un fichero JSON, que posteriormente en una función en flask lo intento guardar en una tabla.

'''

```
<script>
    function duplicarPagina() {

        // Cierra manualmente el modal
        var confirmacionModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('confirmacionModal'));
            confirmacionModal.hide();

        // Recopila los datos del formulario
         var clienteValue = document.getElementById('cliente').textContent;
         var estadoValue = document.getElementById('estado_tarea').textContent;
         var timeValue = document.getElementById('time').value.replaceAll(":", "-");
         var from_dateValue = document.getElementById('from_date').value.replaceAll(":", "-");
         var to_dateValue = document.getElementById('to_date').value.replaceAll(":", "-");
        var formData = {
            'estado': document.getElementById('estado').textContent,
            'cliente': clienteValue,
            'estado_tarea': estadoValue,
            'employee': document.getElementById('employee').value,
            'time': timeValue,
            'priority': document.getElementById('priority').value,
            'from_date': from_dateValue,
            'to_date': to_dateValue,
            'comment': document.getElementById('comment').value.trim()
        };

        fetch('/ruta-flask', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)

        })

        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                throw new Error(`Respuesta no exitosa: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
            }
        })
        .then(data => {
            console.log('Datos parseados:', data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error en la solicitud:', error);
        });
    }

</script>
```

'''

Esta es mi script de JavaScript, y este es mi función en flask:

'''

```
    app.config['TRYTON_DATABASE'] = 'prueba'
    tryton = Tryton(app, configure_jinja=True)
    Plan = tryton.pool.get('ack.plan')

    @app.route('/ruta-flask', methods=['POST'])
    @tryton.transaction()
    def procesar_duplicacion():
       def obtener_datos_duplicados(data):
           return {key: f"{value}" for key, value in data.items()}
       try:
           data = request.get_json()
           duplicados = obtener_datos_duplicados(data)

           pdb.set_trace()
           if duplicados is not None:
               plan = Plan()

               plan.cliente = duplicados.get('cliente', '')
               plan.tecnico = duplicados.get('employee', '')
               plan.nombre = duplicados.get('estado_tarea', '').split()[1] if 'estado_tarea' in duplicados else ''

               # Manejar fechas y horas correctamente
               from_date_parts = duplicados.get('from_date', '').split()
        to_date_parts = duplicados.get('to_date', '').split()
               plan.from_date = from_date_parts[0] if len(from_date_parts) > 0 else ''
               plan.from_hour = from_date_parts[1].replace('-', ':') if len(from_date_parts) > 1 else ''
               plan.to_date = to_date_parts[0] if len(to_date_parts) > 0 else ''
               plan.to_hour = to_date_parts[1].replace('-', ':') if len(to_date_parts) > 1 else ''
               plan.tipo = duplicados.get('estado_tarea', '').split()[0].strip(
            "[]") if 'estado_tarea' in duplicados else ''
               plan.prioridad = duplicados.get('priority', '')
               plan.tiempo = duplicados.get('time', '')
               plan.dedicacion = '-'
               plan.estado = duplicados.get('estado', '')
        
               plan.save()
           else:
               print("No se ha podido guardar")
               return 'Hola'
       except Exception as e:
           print('Error en la función procesar_duplicacion:', str(e))
           return jsonify({'error': 'Ocurrió un error en el servidor'}), 500
```

'''

Basicamente lo que estoy haciendo aquí es mediante la función:

'''
def obtener_datos_duplicados(data):

```
    return {key: f"{value}" for key, value in data.items()}
```

'''
Convierto el Json en un diccionario para poder coger cada una de las keys y poder guardar los valores en la base de datos.

He utilizado la clase:

'''

```
import pdb
```

'''
Para poder hacer debug para comprobar que todos los campos están bien, pero a la hora de ejecutar la app, me da el siguiente error:
'''

```
Error en la función procesar_duplicacion: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Jan/2024 07:30:20] "POST /ruta-flask HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

'''

La verdad es que no se porque me da constantemente este error, agradecería que alguien me lo pudiera aclarar. Gracias.

Comment: Cuando das formato de código, no debes usar comillas simples (') sino acentos graves (_backticks_, `). Por otra parte, pon el error que estás teniendo en el título de la pregunta.

Comment: Como te indica @padaleiana , debes mejorar tu pregunta para que alguien en la comunidad pueda ayudarte. Puedes leer [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Adicional a esto, creo que esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42259166/python-3-valueerror-not-enough-values-to-unpack-expected-3-got-2) podría ayudarte.